# Add css keyframe animation every image switch

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have an image tag where in every 3 seconds it changes to a different image and I want to add into it an animation style where every time the image switch, a css animation keyframe will take effect. It seems that I cant figure out how to apply the animation in javascript. Here's what Ive tried so far:

My javascript,:

```
let indexObj = {

imageChange: document.getElementById("imageChanger"), //id of the image tag
imagePath: ["images/Ps_Logo.png", "images/Pencil.png"],
indexPos: 0,


ChangeImage: () => {

    setInterval(() => {
        indexObj.imageChange.src = indexObj.imagePath[indexObj.indexPos];
        indexObj.imageChange.classList.add("imageToChange"); // imageToChange is the name of the css class where the animation is written on.
        indexObj.indexPos++;
        if (indexObj.indexPos === 2) {
            indexObj.indexPos = 0;
        }
    }, 3000)
  }
}

        indexObj.ChangeImage();
```

Here is my css code. The class and animation keyframe:

```
.imageToChange {
height: 55px;
width: 70x;
border-radius: 20%;
animation-name: animateImage;
animation-duration: .5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animateImage {
0% {
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
}
50% {
    margin-top: 7;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 9px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation only runs the first time you add the `.imageToChange` class (and it does work with your code).

You need to either remove the class after the animation or switch to a different class each time you iterate an image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding and removing (toggling on and off) on your `animateImage` class? Consider adding the animation class and then toggling it after the animation is completed.

You could use the `addClass("imageToChange")` and `removeClass("imageToChange")` jQuery methods: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Or using Vanilla JS toggle a class: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Just be sure to retrigger the event the desired number of times.